# Same looking strings, but different inside. Why? One from $_GET and second from $var=""

Tags: php, google-chrome, url, safari, url-encoding

I'm getting curious results from urls in different browsers.

I had this url in

```
example.com&nam=Oprava skúškovej písomky 2012-2013.png
```

This url was interpreted in **Safari**:

```
example.com&nam=Oprava%20sk%C3%BA%C5%A1kovej%20p%C3%ADsomky%202012-2013.png
```

And in **Chrome** url different:

```
example.com&nam=Oprava%20sku%CC%81s%CC%8Ckovej%20pi%CC%81somky%202012-2013.png
```

Why is this happened? Because Safari link works to picture and Chrome link doesnt work.

And curious staff to end is:

```
echo "<br>".var_dump($_GET['nam']);
echo "<br>".var_dump("Oprava skúškovej písomky 2012-2013.png￼");
```

results

```
string(41) "Oprava skúškovej písomky 2012-2013.png" 
string(44) "Oprava skúškovej písomky 2012-2013.png"
```

These strings look same, but they are different. How can I avoid this? I want two same strings.

Comment: Its because of string escaping. You should better not use not alphanumerical letters in the filenames, also without spaces...

Comment: Is there how to have same string escaping.

Comment: `ú` etc. can be encoded in different ways in UTF-8. (Basically the character `ú` directly, or a simple `u` combined with the diacritic symbol.) _“I want two same strings”_ – then URL-encode the values properly beforehand (in the UTF-8 encoded form you have), instead of letting the browser do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari our slovak `ú` is encoded as `%C3%BA`:

example.com&nam=Oprava%20sk%C3%BA%C5%A1kovej%20p%C3%ADsomky%202012-2013.png

And in Chrome its encoded as `u` + `´`, and it is `u` + `%CC%81`, and also `s` + `ˇ` is `s` + `%CC%8C`:

example.com&nam=Oprava%20sku%CC%81s%CC%8Ckovej%20pi%CC%81somky%202012-2013.png

But it doesnt matter, when its decoded back, its the same string.

And in your var_dump you have different strings:

```
echo "<br>".var_dump($_GET['nam']);
echo "<br>".var_dump("Oprava skúškovej písomky 2012-2013.png￼");
```

In the second one you have  (space) at the end.

Comment: Safari works: http://matfyz.mydevelops.com/matfyz.php?cpkr=79c2b46ce2594ecbcb5b73e928345492&adr=/Predmety/Analyza%201&nam=Oprava%20sk%C3%BA%C5%A1kovej%20p%C3%ADsomky%202012-2013.png&ss=Oprava%20sk%C3%BA%C5%A1kovej%20p%C3%ADsomky%202012-2013.png

Chrome doesnt work:  http://matfyz.mydevelops.com/matfyz.php?cpkr=79c2b46ce2594ecbcb5b73e928345492&adr=/INF/1.%20rok/Zima/Analyza&nam=Oprava%20sku%CC%81s%CC%8Ckovej%20pi%CC%81somky%202012-2013.png&ss=Oprava%20sku%CC%81s%CC%8Ckovej%20pi%CC%81somky%202012-2013.png

So is there way too tell for example rawurlencode() to code escape strings like in safari?

Comment: why do you have in your html header this? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`? its not XML...

Comment: Do you think this causes problem? Ok, lets find out. I try without this header.

Comment: At least it should not be there... only HTML header

Comment: Are you sure using functions `urlencode` and then `urldecode`?

Comment: Well if I use urlencode and decode on that slovak string, it doesnt work on both safari and chrome.

Comment: I also tried use rawurlencode but I`ve got Chrome style encoded string and it doesnt work. I need to force change %CC%81 to %C3%BA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63544/discussion-between-legionar-and-mery-svk).